# color of span and on hover change color is not reflecting in styled component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

i'm using styled component in react

the color of span is not reflecting and remains black,

and if passing html content in children it just hides the content and on hover it shows the content.

i created this button with styled component,

everything works fine but i'm not sure what am i missing.

here is the snippet, a little help needed.

 i'm using MUI Button

```
const StyledSpan = styled.span`
  position: relative;
  color: color: ${(props) => (props?.fontColor ? props.fontColor : colors.black)};
  &:hover {
    transition: all 0.5s;
    color: ${(props) => (props?.noHover ? props?.fontColor : props?.hoverFontColor ? props.hoverFontColor : colors.primary)};
  }
`;

const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  background-color: ${(props) => (props?.backgroundColor ? props.backgroundColor : colors.primary)};
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: ${(props) => (props?.padding ? props.padding : '0px')};
  color: ${(props) => (props?.fontColor ? props.fontColor : colors.black)};
  border: ${(props) => (props?.borderColor ? props.borderColor : 'none')};
  transition: all 0.5s;
  position: relative;
  &::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: 'white';
    background-color: ${(props) => (props?.backgroundColor ? props.backgroundColor : colors.primary)};
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  &::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: 'white';
    border: ${(props) => (props?.hoverBorderColor ? props.hoverBorderColor : `1px solid ${colors.primary}`)};
  }
  &:hover {
    background-color: ${(props) =>
      props?.noHover ? props?.backgroundColor : props?.hoverBackgroundColor ? props.hoverBackgroundColor : colors.primary};
    border: ${(props) =>
      props?.noHover
        ? `1px solid ${props?.backgroundColor}`
        : props?.hoverBorderColor
        ? `${props.hoverBorderColor}`
        : `1px solid ${colors.primary}`};
    color: ${(props) => (props?.noHover ? props?.fontColor : props?.hoverFontColor ? props.hoverFontColor : colors.primary)};
  }
  &:hover::before {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
  }
  &:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
`;

const MyButton = ({
  children,
  backgroundColor,
  hoverBackgroundColor,
  fontColor,
  hoverFontColor,
  borderColor,
  hoverBorderColor,
  padding,
  noHover,
  style,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <StyledButton
      backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
      hoverBackgroundColor={hoverBackgroundColor}
      fontColor={fontColor}
      hoverFontColor={hoverFontColor}
      borderColor={borderColor}
      hoverBorderColor={hoverBorderColor}
      padding={padding}
      noHover={noHover}
      style={style}
      {...props}
    >
      {typeof children === 'string' ? <StyledSpan>{children}</StyledSpan> : children}
    </StyledButton>
  );
};

export default MyButton;
```